# How do I predefine a data frame's size before and inside a for loop in R

Tags: r

I have a rather simple for loop in R that I created which scrapes data from a website and then places it into R. I know the size of the data that I am scraping (row #'s and column #'s), but am having trouble getting the data frame to populate properly. I keep getting weird looking data frames usually not containing my data. The portion of my code that loops through different sections of the website works great, but consolidating all that data into a single data frame is my issue. Also, if I didn't know the exact size of the data I was scraping in, is there a specific way in R where one can define a data frame to accommodate large unspecific data amounts?

Thank you.

Note: My code deals with a specific package which scrapes weather data. I think it might be best not to post the code since it might cause more confusion than necessary due to the package specific syntax, but I will post if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can get full line in one column and then split it as required:

```
> ddf = data.frame(maincol = character(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> 
> for(i in 1:10) ddf[nrow(ddf)+1,]= c(paste("item number:",i))
> ddf
           maincol
1   item number: 1
2   item number: 2
3   item number: 3
4   item number: 4
5   item number: 5
6   item number: 6
7   item number: 7
8   item number: 8
9   item number: 9
10 item number: 10
>
```

For splitting out information:

```
> ddf$newcol = sapply(strsplit(ddf$main, ':'), function(x)x[2])
> 
> ddf
           maincol newcol
1   item number: 1      1
2   item number: 2      2
3   item number: 3      3
4   item number: 4      4
5   item number: 5      5
6   item number: 6      6
7   item number: 7      7
8   item number: 8      8
9   item number: 9      9
10 item number: 10     10
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I attempting to integrate a variation of your example into my code.